# How do you get awk to move to next line when a condition has been actioned?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to write an `awk` script which checks certain conditions and throws away lines meeting those conditions.

The specific condition are to throw away the first two lines of the file and any line that starts with the text `xyzzy:`. To that end, I coded up:

```
awk '
    NR < 2    {}
    /^xyzzy:/ {}
              {print}'
```

thinking that it would throw away the lines where either of those two conditions were met and print otherwise.

Unfortunately, it appears that the `print` is being processed even when the line matches one of the other two patterns.

Is there a C-like `continue` action that will move on the next line ignoring all other condition checks for the current line?

I suppose I *could* use something like `((NR > 1) && (!/^xyzzy:/)) {print}` as the third rule but that seems rather ugly to me.

Alternatively, is there another way to do this?

Comment: I am no expert on `awk` but here is a really nice [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) that I found very helpful when I started learning it. And of course there is a very [elaborative guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) too. But I like tutorials over books. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the keyword `next` as your action

This keyword is often useful when you want to iterate over 2 files; sometimes it's the same file that you want to process twice.

You'll see the following idiom:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {  
  < stuff that works on file 1 only >
  next
}
{
  < stuff that works on file 2 only >
}' ./infile1 ./infile2
```

Comment: Ah, should have tried the Perlish `next` before posting. P.S. I tried `NR =< 2` and it barfed so I'm assuming you meant `NR <= 2` (and fixed accordingly). Cheers.

Comment: `next` is one of **the** best features in `awk`. :)

Comment: @paxdiablo, you mean you should have tried the Awkish `next`, right? Awk came first. :-)

Comment: Can I skip few lines? for example if i am in first line. By doing next, i will move to second line. Can I skip line 2 and move directly to line 3?

Comment: @turbo88 `{ getline; next; }` ?